# Running 'make test' on an individual module for Python 2.7.4 build

Tags: centos, compiling, python

I am working on building [Python 2.7.4](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.7.4/) on CentOS 6.4.  When running the `make test` step, the `test_gdb` step fails, and I would like to get some more info as to why.

Build commands I'm running:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python-2.7.4 --enable-ipv6 --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared
make
make test
```

Output of make test:

> ... test test_gdb failed -- multiple errors occurred; run in verbose
>   mode for details ...

So basically, I'm trying to figure out how to run the `test_gdb` test separately and in verbose mode.  Sounds like I should use `regrtest.py`, but I seem to get `invalid syntax` with the various options I've tried.  Any ideas?

```
banjer@somehost:/usr/local/src/Python-2.7.4> python Lib/test/regrtest.py -v test_gdb
  File "Lib/test/regrtest.py", line 679
    'test_support',
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Usually you just need to install a bunch of devel packages. Also make sure gdb is actually installed. I think there is a "Development" group also.

Comment: @Keith I'll definitely need to fix gdb, and you're probably right that I'm missing some devel headers.  My question is more on how to run a single make test to get more detail as to why its failing, not just for gdb.  On a side note, I'm running into this [MAXREPEAT bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=704084) when I skip the tests, install python with `make install` and run python.  Thats why I'm going through and making sure all the tests come out successfully first.

Comment: I'm afraid that's just how the stock unittest framework works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual lines around 679 in Lib/test/regrtest.py are:

```
NOTTESTS = {
    'test_support',
    'test_future1',
    'test_future2',
}
```

This defines a mutable set and is syntax back-ported from 3.1 to 2.7. This syntax is **not** available in 2.6 or earlier version of python.

That your test raises a syntax error is probably because your default python is pre-2.7. If you would have executed:

```
./python Lib/test/regrtest.py -v test_gdb
^-- this is the difference
```

in that directory, you would have been testing the `python` executable you just compiled and not the default one provided in your path. Using that executable you are unlikely to get this particular error (but maybe others that are really `gdb` related).

Comment: You nailed it.  The default `python` in my PATH was 2.6.  Using the newly compiled python instead with `./python`, I was able to actually run the individual test.  Cheers!